# Documentation for Psych to_yaml options?

Tags: ruby, yaml, psych

Ruby 1.9.3 defaults to using [Psych](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych) for YAML. While [the ruby-doc documentation for it](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/)  is *completely lacking*, I was able to find one external piece of documentation that hinted that the `indentation` option is supported. This was borne out in testing:

```
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
#=> "1.9.3"
irb(main):002:0> require 'yaml'
#=> true
irb(main):003:0> [[[1]]].to_yaml
#=> "---\n- - - 1\n"
irb(main):009:0> [[[1]]].to_yaml indentation:9
#=> "---\n-        -        - 1\n"
```

There are presumably more options supported. Specifically, I want to know how to change the line wrap width or disable it altogether.

**What are the options available?**

Comment: After looking at the source of 2.2.0, a short update: It seems there are very few options right now, hence little documentation still.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Deep in the guts of `ruby-1.9.3-p125/ext/psych/emitter.c` I found three options:

- `indentation` - *The level must be less than 10 and greater than 1.*
- `line_width` - *Set the preferred line width.*
- `canonical` - *Set the output style to canonical, or not (true/false).*

And they work!

Comment: So, it seems you can't disable line wrap? I tried `line_width: 0` and with `nil` which do not have any effect. `true` returns an error.

Comment: @sawa You want `line_width:999` or some other sufficiently large number.

Comment: It seems Syck options doesn't work too. So these ones for Psych are only avalible for 1.9.3

Comment: I had line_width to 999, which still had some weird newlines.  -1 worked, thanks @sawa

Answer (score 19):

When you want to disable line wrap, use this option:

```
line_width: -1
```

Comment: Neither `foo.to_yaml(line_width: -1)` or `foo.to_yaml(options = {line_width: -1})` is working for me in ruby 2.5.x