# Show square brackets in yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

How to generate content in yml file with this format:

```
required_groups:
- ["member", "cn=serviceboard-users,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=int,dc=dostack,dc=io"]
```

Instead of this format:

```
required_groups:
- - member
  - cn=serviceboard-users,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=int,dc=dostack,dc=io
```

Input:

```
[["member", "cn=serviceboard-users,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=int,dc=dostack,dc=io"]]
```

Current Code:

```
File.open("config/ldap/#{Rails.env}.yml", "w") do |file|
  data = {}

  formatted_groups_array = []
  Setting.ldap_users_filter_required_groups.each { |group| formatted_groups_array.push([Setting.ldap_group_membership_attribute.to_s, group.to_s])}
  data["required_groups"] = formatted_groups_array

  file.write(data.to_yaml)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9759344/681409), the default ruby library `Psych` does not have many options available, and you cannot customize the output the way you are trying to do.

In the meantime I've found an [old possibile custom solution](https://gist.github.com/lyoshenka/4680297) to your problem, but I had to rewrite a small part of it to make it compatible to the most recent ruby version (I am using 2.7.0 for this example). This is my [updated script](https://gist.github.com/marzapower/5b030e036284243f8feb1c801440bc8d). Basically it will introduce a new way to edit the YAML output using a more concise syntax.

You can use it this way:

```
 File.open("config/ldap/#{Rails.env}.yml", "w") do |file|
  data = {}

  formatted_groups_array = []
  Setting.ldap_users_filter_required_groups.each { |group| formatted_groups_array.push([Setting.ldap_group_membership_attribute.to_s, group.to_s])}
  data["required_groups"] = formatted_groups_array
  
  styled_yaml = StyledYAML.inline(data)
  file.write(StyledYAML.dump(styled_yaml))
end
```